# Using google charts to create a table from an already existing table

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-visualization

Trying to generate a webpage that uses an API to get some data (in this case, some data from a site that tracks trending hashtags on twitter) and show the data in a Google Chart.

Now, I've already used this API call to successfully get data do a bar chart and a pie chart, but cannot get a table to work properly.

HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
<title>Top Tweets from Grand NCE</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8" />

<!-- Code to implement Google charts -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["table"]});
</script>

<!-- jQuery AJAX code & DrawChart code -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="PageThree.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px; margin:0 auto">Loading...  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript Code:

```
//calls the API on page load
$(function() {

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    cache: false,
    url: "http://academiamap.com/content.php?call=getTrendingTopics&startTime=2013-9-05%2000:00:00&endTime=2013-10-11%2000:00:00&seedUserList=GRAND_NCE",
    success: function(data) {

        data = eval(data); 

        chartData = new Array();
        chartData[0] = ['Hashtag', 'Tweets'];
        for (i=1; i<=data.length; i++) { 
            chartData[i] = new Array();
            chartData[i] = [data[i-1]['tag'], parseInt(data[i-1]['count'])]; 
        }

        console.log(chartData);

        drawChart1(chartData); 
    }
});

});


function drawChart1(dataArray) {
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(dataArray);

var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));     //draw chart to "table_div"
table.draw(data, options);
}
```

I'm new at using Web API's and javascript, so any help is appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You almost have it right; there are only a couple of things you should change.  First, you want to run your AJAX call from a callback of the google loader, not on page load, as the Visualization API is not guaranteed to have finished loading by the time the page "ready" event fires.  Second, you should set the `dataType` AJAX parameter to "json" - this will tell jQuery to parse the returned data as JSON and not as a string; this avoids the dangerous `eval` statement, which will execute any javascript it finds in the string.  There are improvements you can make elsewhere, but it's all just code cleanup (condensing multi-line statements down to one line, removing redundant code).  Here's one way you could write the AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    cache: false,
    url: "http://academiamap.com/content.php?call=getTrendingTopics&startTime=2013-9-05%2000:00:00&endTime=2013-10-11%2000:00:00&seedUserList=GRAND_NCE",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(json) {
        var dataArray = [['Hashtag', 'Tweets']];
        for (i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
            dataArray.push([json[i]['tag'], parseInt(json[i]['count'])]); 
        }
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(dataArray);

        var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));
        table.draw(data, {});
    }
});
```

Here's a jsfiddle with this code sample that you can play with: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/3vbub/